# Android studio could not build and run in my windows 7 OS

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-2.3

I am newbie for android development :)

Install android studio from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html.

After install i start develop sample application which is available in android studio website, after complete that sample project i try to build and run app. It ask to run a simulator for android phone, i select API27 - Nexus 7.

I am not able to process further it thrown error, after simulator getting crashed. below mentioned that issue.

My PC Intel core 3, is there any configuration is need for boot config itself.

```
daemon started successfull

Executing tasks:[:app:assembleDebug]

Gradle build finished in 12s 793ms

Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. 
A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in 
a future release. 

Emulator: WARNING: init: Missing WGL extension WGL_ARB_create_context

Emulator: glTextImage2D: got err pre:(0x506 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to update my drivers. Update Intel drivers with help of.
Intel® Driver & Support Assistant

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html,

First time android simulator loaded slowly after that it loaded properly and faster.